# Plotting Inline with IPython Console in PyDev

Tags: pydev, ipython

Just installed pyDev and eclipse. I see that the console is an IPython console, but when Im trying to plot, I need to use the show() command instead of the plots just appearing inline like a regular IPython console. I've tried to use %pylab inline but there is no such magic.

The console loads IPython 1.1.0. What do I need to do to get inline figures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, that's correct, the PyDev console is not able to show images such as you'd have on IPython notebook (which is an HTML viewer in the end), so, you need to show the plot widget to see the results (note that the plot should be interactive and shouldn't halt the console in the latest version).

It should be possible to create a special view in PyDev where those results could be seen in an HTML viewer, but there are currently no plans to do so.

Comment: mmm.. that's a shame. BTW, you can plot on a regular IPython console, outside of a broswer. is this HTML based also?

Comment: I believe you're referring to the IPython gui which is PyQt based... in this case, I'm not sure... they can be doing the drawing manually based on Qt capabilities or using a Qt HTML-based widget. Either way, this would require more work to be integrated into PyDev (i.e.: it acts more as the IPython in a command line shell and not on a special widget to draw contents).